# Scope and nesting functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Hello everyone once again I am a little confused. the challenge I am aiming at is thus:

Create a function named `fullNameAndAge` that accepts 3 parameters called `firstName`, `lastName` and `age`. 
Within `fullNameAndAge`, call the `fullName` function by passing in `firstName` and `lastName` variables as parameters into it and store the result of that function in a variable named `result`. 
Now return the full name as the age separated by a comma and a space. (e.g `fullNameAndAge(“Jane”, “Doe”, 23)` would return `'Jane Doe, 23'`

the answer key states `fullNameAndAge("Jonah", "Hex", 46)` should return `"Jonah Hex, 46"`.

Below is one of my attempts:

```js
    function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    }

     // your code under here
    function fullNameAndAge(firstName, lastName, age) {
        var result = null;

        function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
            result = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
            return result;
        }

        fullName(firstName, lastName);
        return result + ' , ' + age;
    }

    return fullNameAndAge('Jonah', 'Hex', 46);
```

I feel like I'm on the mark but not yet there. I'm Not sure where I messed up.

Comment: its already returning 'Jane Doe, 23' for me, what is the problem you have?

Comment: I'm getting "syntax error: illegal return statement"

Comment: your last line is a return statement not inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is a return statement not inside a function

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller

you can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Thanks to you Chris, I figured it out. The proper code was: 

function fullNameAndAge ( firstName, lastName, age) {  
  var result = firstName + ' ' + lastName; return (result + ', ' + age);

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor function and `fullName` to it's prototype

```js
function FullNameAndAge(firstName, lastName, age) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
}


FullNameAndAge.prototype.fullName = function() {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ',' + this.age;

}

let m = new FullNameAndAge('Jonah', 'Hex', 46).fullName();
console.log(m)
```